# Removing empty nodes with empty/no attributes using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to:

- remove all empty nodes with no or all empty attributes f.e. `<node/>`, `<node attr1="" attr2=""/>, <node></node>`
- keep those nodes, which has at least one non-empty attribute f.e. `<node attr1="123" attr2="" attr3=""/>` and then remove those empty attributes to have `<node attr1="123"/>`

---

- **UPDATED** keep those empty nodes, which have at least one non-empty child nodes, or which have at least one node with some attributes

**EXAMPLE**

Before

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c attr="1"/>
    <d/>
  </b>
</a>
```

After

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c attr="1"/>
  </b>
</a>
```

---

I have following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != '' or ./@* != ''">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select = "@*[.!='']"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

It works pretty good, BUT only if my XML has at least one non-empty node!
Example:

XML:

```
<ns1:form xmlns:ns1="http://aaa.com">
  <ns1:test>
    <a></a>
    <b attr1=""/>
    <c attr="123"/>
    <d attr="">
      <e attr="12">NOT EMPTY NODE</e>
    </d>
  </ns1:test>
</ns1:form>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns1:form xmlns:ns1="http://aaa.com">
  <ns1:test>
    <c attr="123"/>
    <d>
      <e attr="12">NOT EMPTY NODE</e>
    </d>
  </ns1:test>
</ns1:form>
```

Works fine, but skipping this non-empty node :

```
<ns1:form xmlns:ns1="http://aaa.com">
  <ns1:test>
    <a></a>
    <b attr1=""/>
    <c attr="123"/>
    <d attr="">
      <e attr="12"></e>
    </d>
  </ns1:test>
</ns1:form>
```

the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Anyone has any idea why it works like this? My code :

```
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("transform.xslt"));

    Source xslt = new StreamSource(in);
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
    Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));

    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
    Source text = new StreamSource(reader);
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(writer));
```

Cheers

**UPDATE**

After using your XSLT the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns1:form xmlns:ns1="http://aaa.com">
<ns1:test>


<c attr="123"/>
<d>
    <e attr="12">e</e>
</d>
</ns1:test>
</ns1:form>
```

I wonder why there are empty spaces in my output.xml?

---

Generally speaking, empty node is a node, which

1) istelf has no attributes or all empty AND

2) has no value f.e. `<a></a>`, `<b/>` AND

3) has no children which carry any data (has no children which meet the requirements 1 and 2)
Example explaining empty nodes:

```
<a>
  <b attr="1">
  </b>
  <c>
  <d attr="2">
    <e> value </e>
    <f></f>
  </d>
</a>
```

a is not empty because it has child `b` with attribute `attr="1"` (it's enough, but it also has: x, xx, xxx)

b is not empty because it has non-empty attribute

c is not empty because it has `d` node with attribute `attr="2"` (x) and also has child `e` with some value  (xxx)

d is not empty becuase it has non-empty attribute (xx)

e is not empty because it has a value (xxx)

f is empty

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly an "empty node" is? It seems like you mean an element with no child *text* nodes - but it would be best to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I've updated my question explaining what does empty node exactly mean to me.

Comment: Also see my example at the top: I want to keep a,b,c (c - has an attribute; a - has child c which has attribute; b - has child c which has attribute) )node but to remove d (has no children which carry any data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not make `<xsl:apply-templates/>` conditional - otherwise the stylesheet will stop at the first node that does not satisfy the condition, and it will never get to its children.

---

BTW, if understand your conditions correctly, you could simplify this to:

```
<xsl:template match="*[string() or @*[string()]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select = "@*[string()]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, If I remove <xsl:apply-tempates/>, no matter If I have one non-empty node or not, the output is always: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: I didn't say you should remove it; on the contrary, you need to have it even if the condition is false.

Comment: Thanks Michael - you're great. I guess I need to study XSLT, I'm a newbie at the moment. Two questions: 1) What does exactly string() do? I have trouble finding any reference .. 2) Your XSLT works fine, but it leaves empty spaces and I wonder why? I've updated my question showing example.

Comment: **1.** String: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-ebv **2.** Add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to the top level of your stylesheet.

Comment: Hey Michael , it turned out that it works not exactly the way I wanted: completely my fault. I forgot to mention, that I want to keep all those empty nodes, which have any non-empty child or empty-child with any non-empty attribute. I've updated my question at the top, I'd be glad if you could look at it..